# manipulation of XML textnode with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i want to delete some unwanted text from the following data with xslt

```
Address>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  (Part Of) Null</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Flat  - Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
</Rowinfo>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Flat  - Buena Villa House 1</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Flat  3a  Anderson's House</LocatorName>
</Rowinfo>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a Funlife Building 02a</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>office Unit 2a   Funlife Building  <LocatorName>
 </Rowinfo>
 </Address>
```

to produce this

```
<LocatorDesignator>Dwelling(Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName>Buena Villa House</LocatorName>

<LocatorDesignator>Flat 1</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName> Anderson's House</LocatorName>

<LocatorDesignator>office Unit 2a</LocatorDesignator>
<LocatorName> Funlife Building  <LocatorName>
```

In Locatorname: Extract

- Buena Villa House
- Anderson's House
- Funlife Building

in other words the part in double quotes are to be deleteed :

```
(row1) "Flat  -" Buena Villa House.   
(row2) "Flat  3a"  Anderson's House .
(row3) "office Unit 2a"   Funlife Building.
```

In Locatordesignator: Delete

- NULL
- Buena Villa House
- Funlife Building

in other words the part in double quotes are to be deleted :

```
(row1) Dwelling  (Part Of) "Null"
(row2) Flat  " Buena Villa House" 1.   
(row3) office Unit 2a   "Funlife Building 02a".
```

Comment: meaning you don't even want to figure out working code?

Comment: Is Artificial Intelligence an option? Substring manipulation seems incapable of what you want...

Comment: lee, you have to explain what must be changed into what -- this isn't obvious at all. In one text node you are removing "Flat  - " and leaving "Buena Villa House". However, in another text node you are removing "  - Buena Villa House " and leaving "Flat" and "1". This is very confusing! Please, edit the question and describe the exact requirements that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:LocatornameDeletes>
  <del>Flat  -</del>
  <del>Flat  3a</del>
  <del>office Unit 2a</del>
 </my:LocatornameDeletes>

 <my:LocatordesignatorDeletes>
  <del>Null</del>
  <del>Buena Villa House</del>
  <del>Funlife Building 02a</del>
 </my:LocatordesignatorDeletes>

 <xsl:variable name="vLocNameDels" select="document('')/*/my:LocatornameDeletes/*"/>    
 <xsl:variable name="vLocDesDels" select="document('')/*/my:LocatordesignatorDeletes/*"/>   
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LocatorName/text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="makeDeletes">
   <xsl:with-param name="pDeletes" select="$vLocNameDels"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="LocatorDesignator/text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="makeDeletes">
   <xsl:with-param name="pDeletes" select="$vLocDesDels"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="makeDeletes">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDeletes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vDelText" select="$pDeletes[contains($pText, .)][1]"/>
  <xsl:if test="$vDelText">
   <xsl:variable name="vRough">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $vDelText)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($pText, $vDelText)"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($vRough)"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on (the corrected for malformedness) provided XML document**:

```
<Address>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  (Part Of) Null</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  - Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Flat  - Buena Villa House 1</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>Flat  3a  Anderson's House</LocatorName>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a Funlife Building 02a</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>office Unit 2a   Funlife Building  </LocatorName>
    </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Address>
   <Rowinfo>
      <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling (Part Of)</LocatorDesignator>
      <LocatorName>Buena Villa House</LocatorName>
   </Rowinfo>
   <Rowinfo>
      <LocatorDesignator>Flat - 1</LocatorDesignator>
      <LocatorName>Anderson's House</LocatorName>
   </Rowinfo>
   <Rowinfo>
      <LocatorDesignator>Offices Unit 2a</LocatorDesignator>
      <LocatorName>Funlife Building</LocatorName>
   </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The strings to be deleted in the text-node children of `LocatorName` are provided in the global-level element `my:LocatornameDeletes`.
2. The strings to be deleted in the text-node children of `LocatorDesignator` are provided in the global-level element `my:LocatordesignatorDeletes`.
3. The identity rule copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
4. There are two templates that overide the identity template -- one matching `LocatorName/text()` and the other matching `LocatorDesignator/text()`. Each of these templates simply calls the `makeDeletes` template, passing it as parameter the correct node-set containing the substrings to be deleted.
5. The `makeDeletes` template performs the actual "deletion of the substrings that are passed in its `$pDeletes` parameter. This is done using a combination of the standard XPath functions [**`substring-before()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before) and [**`substring-after()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-after) .

Comment: @ Dimitre am have syntax errors with xmlns:my="my:my">  what is it?     ERROR: F [Saxon6.5.5] The prefix "my" for element "my:LocatornameDeletes" is not bound.

Comment: @lee, You obviously have a copy/paste error -- please copy the *whole* thransformation and paste it into your window. `xmlns:something="some URI"` is a namespace declaration.

Comment: @lee, I added the requested explanation.

Comment: @lee, I dont understand -- what do you mean by "jump a row"?

Comment: sorry i meant not to delete any value in one row and move to the next for deletion. for example after deleting a value from the first row, moves to the second row and not delete then to the third row and delete

Comment: @lee, just append the `match` attribute of the template with `[position() mod 2 = 1]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15827/discussion-between-lee-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Comment: @ Dimitre, am having a hard time preventing the provided codes from deleting some values in the text node. As your codes delete all the values in a text node unless unless you assign a value to be deleted. in the case where there is no value to be deleted?

Comment: @lee, Please, search the answers for two-pass transformation -- everything will be safe if you applyone transformation on the result of the previous transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these string functions in XSLT 1.0 to achieve your goals:

1. contains()
2. substring()
3. substring-before()
4. substring-after()

Google the function names together with XSLT to get the specification for each function.

If you can upgrade to XSLT 2.0, I would definitely recommend it. In XSLT 2.0, you will be able to use regex to achieve your goals much simpler.

### Example

With this input document...

```
<t>
 <row>"Flat  -" Buena Villa House.</row>  
 <row>"Flat  3a"  Anderson's House .</row>
 <row>"office Unit 2a"   Funlife Building.</row>
</t>
```

...when this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet is applied to said document, will remove the double-quoted text fragments...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <t>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/row"/>
 </t>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
 <row>
  <xsl:call-template name="remove-quoted-bit">
    <xsl:with-param name="raw-text" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>  
 </row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="remove-quoted-bit">
  <xsl:param name="raw-text" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($raw-text,'&quot;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        substring-before($raw-text,'&quot;'),
        substring-after( substring-after($raw-text,'&quot;'),'&quot;')
        )" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$raw-text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>  
  </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and produce this output...

```
<t>
  <row> Buena Villa House.</row>
  <row>  Anderson's House .</row>
  <row>   Funlife Building.</row>
</t>
```

#### Update

Grammar edited.

Comment: Sean, it is correct to say that the stylesheet (or transformation) is applied to the XML document -- not the reverse.

Comment: Sean B, am mixing it all up, could you kindly edit it based on the data(elements). thank you

Comment: @Lee, I don't understand what you want, because your original document does not have any double quotes, but the amended part of your question is framed in terms "part in double quotes". It's a contradiction. In any case, you should be satisfied with Dimitre's comprehensive answer. My answer was intended to be illustrative and directional only.